# Identifying and selecting single elements from a huge data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have the following data frame in **R**:

```
V1    V2             V3
A     3.5 - 5.5      2
B     3.5 - 5.5      2.2 - 5.0 
C     18 - 25        3.5
D     0.6 - 1.5      3 - 4.7
E     30             2.3 - 3 
F     11.0 - 13.0    1
G     6.5 - 8.5      3 - 5
H     16 - 19        4 - 10
I     1.5 - 2.0      2
J     11.0 - 14.0    3
K     1.2            5
L     32             7
M     31             8
```

The list is huge (> 100,000 rows). I want to identify all rows that containing the single numbers in data frame and then generate a second data frame, like:

```
V1    V2
E     30
K     1.2
L     32
M     31
```

and:

```
V1    V3 
A     2
C     3.5
F     1
I     2
J     3
K     5
L     7
M     8
```

What is the best way to select the single numbers rows? I'm trying to figure out with gsub command, but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the hyphen and negate it.  `grepl()` would work well for that.

```
df[!grepl("-", df$V2, fixed = TRUE), -3]
#    V1  V2
# 5   E  30
# 11  K 1.2
# 12  L  32
# 13  M  31
```

and the same for `V3` (with `-2`)

```
df[!grepl("-", df$V3, fixed = TRUE), -2]
#    V1  V3
# 1   A   2
# 3   C 3.5
# 6   F   1
# 9   I   2
# 10  J   3
# 11  K   5
# 12  L   7
# 13  M   8
```

**Update:** As Frank noted, you can do this with `is.na()`, and it actually might be better to coerce your data to numeric anyway if you plan to use it for calculations.  In that case, if `V2` and `V3` are factors, you can do

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
```

and if they are characters

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)
```

Then you can simply subset for the negation of `is.na()`.

```
df[!is.na(df$V2), -3]
#    V1   V2
# 5   E 30.0
# 11  K  1.2
# 12  L 32.0
# 13  M 31.0
```

... and so on.

Comment: Or `!is.na(as.numeric(df$V2))`?

Comment: or `grep(..., invert=TRUE)`